# Eliminating concurrency bugs with mutexes

Tags: c, concurrency, mutex

There are multiple threads each with the same format, running different actions eg. thread2 runs actions21-28 etc.

```
void *Thread1(void *threadid) {
    action11();
    action12();
    action13();
    action14();
    action15();
    action16();
    action17();
    while (!((gS == 7))) {};
    action18();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Each action then looks like this:

```
void action11() {
    int loc1;
    loc1 = 8;
    gK = loc1;
}
```

gK being a global variable declared elsewhere as 0. Other actions are almost the exact same calling different global variables, however some actions would be slightly different such as these critical actions:

```
void action13() {
    int loc1;
    loc1 = 8;
    gH = (gH + loc1);
}

void action16() {
    int loc1;
    loc1 = 2;
    gV = (gL * loc1);
    int loc2;
    loc2 = 10;
    gL = (gV + loc2);
}
```

these actions are calling other global variables modified by other actions.
The program is supposed to run concurrently, however there are bugs with modifying values too early or too late so I need to use mutexes within these thread functions to fix these, but I dont understand where to place them. I think the end result should have the global variables all be the same value on each run, eg.

```
start: gK = 0, gZ = 0, gP = 0, etc
end: gK = x, gZ = y, gP = z etc 
start: gK = 0, gZ = 0, gP = 0, etc
end: gK = x, gZ = y, gP = z etc
```

I tried locking and unlocking mutexes at the start and end of each thread but this just makes it a sequential program not concurrent. I also tried locking before and after each critical action is called, but the final values are still different every run eg

```
start: gK = 0, gZ = 0, gP = 0, etc
end: gK = x, gZ = y, gP = z etc 
start: gK = 0, gZ = 0, gP = 0, etc
end: gK = i, gZ = j, gP = k etc
```

Comment: _"I need to use mutexes within these thread functions to fix these, but I dont understand where to place them"_ - Lock the mutex before writing to a variable that may be read by other threads. Unlock it when you have written the new value to the variable. Lock the mutex before reading from the same variable and unlock it when you've read the value the variable holds. You could also use atomic variables.

Comment: @TedLyngmo One example would be action12 in thread1, action36 in thread3, action55 in thread5. These 3 actions all modify the same variable in different threads. If i lock before and after each call, does it matter then if the actions are executed in different orders on different runs? For example on one run action11 would go first, then action36 then action55, but on another run it would be 12,55,36.

Comment: typo: "action11" here should say "action12"

Comment: It _can_ matter. Lets say you are adding to a floating point variable where some numbers are small and some very big for example.  In that case you may observe different results in every run. if this is a concern, try to use integers or wait until all threads are done, then sort the floats and sum them up sequentially. Part of the analysis when using threads is to figure out what parts that can actually be executed simultaneously so you need to take a look at your functions and figure out if it matters if one operation in one thread must come before another operation in another thread.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I dont really understand sorry. I was tasked with removing concurrency bugs by adding in mutex and conditional variables where necessary. I dont think there is anymore information I can give surrounding the problem. 
When you say lock the mutex before writing to a variable and unlock after, then do the same for each thread with the same variable, as I did with action12,36,55. There is another case with a different variable modified in 25,33,42,51,56. For these do I again just lock and unlock around each action? What is this actually doing, as im not using any cond_signal/wait?

Comment: To be able to do this properly, get an understanding of what the algorithm is supposed to be doing. Since it's full of bugs, just drop the old threading code and start over with a sequential algorithm that works 100% of the time, _then_ analyze what parts of it that could be parallelized. Just sprinkling mutexes all over code that is this badly broken will most probably create a patchwork that is not very efficient. It's often possible to parallelize parts of a bigger computation without using _any_ mutexes if one adds a fast sequential step after the subcomputations are done.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I believe the output can be different each time. I added mutex lock and unlock around each action that modifies a variable accessed by 2 or more threads and now I am currently running the program a million times and not getting any deadlock so far, however I notice some actions are running twice back to back. When using these mutexes, do I use a different mutex variable name for each case or can it always be the same, also I have not used any cond_signal/wait, should I be using these?

Comment: It all depends on what dependencies there are between the modifications.  Running back-to-back multiple times is just the way it goes. It's the OS scheduler that decides what thread that will get running time. If you need a conditional variable or not is also very dependent on what the algorithm is supposed to do. If you present the specification of what the algorithm is actually solving and then show how it's solved with threads @ [codereview](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) someone may be able to help out.